# ¿ mysql en whiles?

Tags: mysqldb

Tengo una duda que quisiera que me proporcionaran un poco de ayuda, bueno quisiera saber si se puede realizar un solo while en php para varias consultas mysql o es un while para cada consulta realizada?Esto para generar reportes en excel con ayuda de la librería phpExcel, agradeceria que alguien me pudiera dar un ejemplo en caso de que si se pueda. Gracias

Comment: Reduce al mínimo las conexiones al servidor de base de datos. Si puedes hacer una sola consulta con todos los registros hazla. Si son varias consultas que dependan de algo, estudia los [procedimientos almacenados](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-create-procedure-5346/), pero siempre ten en mente que las conexiones deben ser las mínimas.

Comment: Por cierto, ¡bienvenida al sitio! te recomiendo que pases al [tour] del sitio y a [ask], esta clase de preguntas no son exactamente bien recibidas.